# Xcode crashes when creating a new project

Tags: xcode, macos

Every time I try to create a new project in Xcode, the first window, which asks me for the kind of project I want to create, comes up, but after 5 
seconds Xcode completely crashes:

> Dyld Error Message:   Library not loaded:
>   @rpath/IBCocoaTouchToolFoundation.framework/IBCocoaTouchToolFoundation
>   Referenced from:
>   /Volumes/VOLUME/executable_path=/*/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Overlays/Interface
>   Builder Cocoa Touch Tool   Reason: image not found

Creating a playground works, but when Xcode tries to compile it, it fails:

> Playground execution terminated because the playground process exited
>   unexpectedly.

Also my previously working project doesn't build anymore with following error:

> Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning
>   message and any useful information you can provide. Command
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool
>   failed with exit code 255

When selecting the `main.storyboard` or `launchscreen.xib` in the navigator, it also crashes immediately without any error-message afterwards.

I already re-installed Xcode multiple times, which didn't change anything.
I'm running OS 10.11 Public Beta 3 on a MacBook Pro mid 2014

Comment: update to the latest beta and latest xcode. You also never stated what xcode version you are running

Comment: I'm using both, the latest beta and Xcode (Version 6.4 (6E35b)) available to me.

Comment: There was a bug in that beta that prevented that. We are currently in Beta 6 for 10.11. I would suggest updating to that and maybe trying xcode 7

Comment: Ah ok. Well, that's the problem when you aren't in developer-program. Probably I will just have to wait for the public releases...

Comment: oh your not?? Hmm.. I dont know wish I could help someway. Sorry

Comment: you did, because now I know I just have to wait and didn't destroy my project :)